# Trying to run this query but says unrecognized name even though the table and column are in the table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT
    employees.name AS employees_name,
    employee.role AS employee_role,
    departments.name AS departments_name
FROM
    `employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
    employee_data.departments ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

It says "unrecognized name" in the last line even though I know that the table and column exist.

Comment: Either add the project id to the table names and/or alias your table names. `e` for employees and `d` for departments would be good here. `... from employee_data.employees e join employee_data.departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id`. Also, not sure if BQ wants backticks on all table names. You used them only for the first one.

Comment: Doesn't 'departments' need to be in a JOIN statement? Otherwise you can't access anything in 'departments'.  This applies to 'employee' also.

Answer (score 0):

You are using aliases for all your column names but you haven’t provided those aliases against your tables